Replacing only the key attribute and not the text content in marklogic doc
Let's say we have a doc as:
<node>
<name>Shivangi</name>
<desig>Software Engineer</desig>
</node>

I want it to be changed to:
<node>
<FirstName>Shivangi</FirstName>
<desig>Software Engineer</desig>
</node>


You can replace the name element with a FirstName element constructed with the text() from the original name, and then use xdmp:node-replace():
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := doc("/test.xml")
let $name := $doc/node/name 
return xdmp:node-replace($name, <FirstName>{$name/text()}</FirstName>)

